# When a hard drive powers off when it is inactive doe it cause a click on power up?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, event-log

As the title suggests really.

I've got a new laptop and every now and then it clicks quite loudly.

I thought it might be the hard drive powering up after being idle but I am not sure.

(It clicked whilst I was typing this and the sound is coming from the area where the cd drive and HDD are)

Tried looking in the event logs but could not find anything. I've tried multiple HDD diagnostic software and it passes them all.

The laptop has HDD protection but this only parks the head if the laptop is being moved (which does make a sound/or is inaudible) so I don't think its that.

Now I'm bit stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the drive with [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) to start.
The clicking noise is usually from the head parking on idle.
However, it could be a bad drive and since your laptop is new and would probably be covered by warranty, it would be a good idea to get it checked too.

<sup>The [non-Pro version of HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/download.html) is free for personal use.</sup>

**Update**: If you are sure it is not clicking to park, the drive may be [heading towards its death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death).

> Click of death is a term that became common in the late 1990s referring to the clicking sound in disk storage systems that signals the device has failed, often catastrophically. The term is also used specifically to refer to the failure of portable Iomega Zip drives. The "click of death" can also be an informal warning system before the data on a data drive is lost.

I don't think such problems show up on usual OS error/event logs.
They are more likely to show up with HDTune like diagnostic tools -- but, don't wait.

Comment: I've already used a lot of different Diagnostic tools. And they say the HDD is fine. Also it doesn't make a clicking noise (that I can hear) when it parks.

Comment: Gutting I've only had the laptop about a week (A replacement too!). Toshiba has some built in software that shows a realtime 3D view of the HDD. When it shows it parking it does not click the same as described. I'll try HD Tune and see what that comes up with.

Comment: Toshiba has some custom hardware techniques. The 3D Impact sensor is a good trick. But, I had bad experience with the batteries of a Portage model. It drained when completely powered off -- only when I pulled out the batteries would they stop draining. Have you checked your battery life?

Comment: Battery seems fine. Still waiting for HD Tune to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking could be quite a bad sign-It's one of the indications that the hard drive will fail. For me, the clicking went on luckily for around 8 months from the beginning of the hard drive, and the clicking soon became frequent and more faster, until in the end, it had a series of loud clicks and the hard drive failed.

Comment: That doesn't sound good then. The laptop is new too...